# How does $x^5-5$ factor over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for different values of $p$ mod 5?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

For $p \neq 5$, I need to find the degrees of the factors of $f(x)=x^5-5$ in the cases where

a) $p \equiv 2$ or $3$ mod $5$ (show $f$ is the product of a linear factor and irreducible quartic over $\mathbb{F}_p$)

b) $p \equiv 1$ mod $5$ (show $f$ is either irreducible or splits completely)

---

So far, I have found the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ to be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{5},\omega)$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $5$th root of unity, and this splitting field has degree $20$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. This immediately shows that $f$ cannot have an irreducible cubic as a factor since $3$ does not divide $20$ yet we know $\text{Gal}(f/\mathbb{Q})$ contains an element of cycle type corresponding to the irreducible factorization of $f$ mod $\mathbb{F}_p$. However I am not sure how to generalize this to the cases where $p$ takes different values mod $5$ - my initial thought was to consider using Fermat's Little Theorem but working backwards from a general value of $p$ doesn't seem to be working. In addition, the criterion where you use the cycle types of the factors mod $p$ to find orders of elements in the Galois group also doesn't seem to help since we effectively already know what the group is.

Comment: There isn't really any Galois theory involved here--this is just a little number theory.  Think about what you can say about the roots of $f$ mod $p$ (i.e., the 5th roots of 5 mod $p$).

Comment: There is also the case $p \equiv 4 \bmod 5$ (same as  $p \equiv 9 \bmod 10$), when $f$ splits into a linear factor and two quadratic factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is really no Galois theory involved here. Consider the map
$$\varphi:\ \Bbb{F}_p^{\times}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{F}_p^{\times}:\ x\ \longmapsto\ x^5.$$
This is a group homomorphism of cyclic groups. If $p\not\equiv1\pmod{5}$ then it is injective, and so there is a unique $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_p$ such that $\alpha^5=5$, meaning that $x^5-5$ has a unique linear factor. Then it remains to show that $x^5-5$ does not have a quadratic factor.

On the other hand, if $p\equiv1\pmod{5}$ then $|\ker\varphi|=5$, so either $x^5-5$ has no roots or it splits completely. Again it remains to show that $x^5-5$ does not have a quadratic factor.